# Ubuntu Screen is on Zoom in Default

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-gnome

I just recently installed my Ubuntu 20.04 following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt5Lu_ltPkU&t=274s

but my problem is that my screen is on zoom in default like this one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaF09.png)

I was able to get out of this one yesterday after I installed 22.04, but now I installed 20.04, I can't seem to work this one out. Universal access' zoom is off and I only have on resolution option in my display settings which is the one I'm currently using right now.

Plus, my audio jack is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Your mention four actual systems, so please be precise with details. Are you using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (with GNOME), Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (with LXQt), Kubuntu 20.04 LTS (with KDE Plasma) or Xubuntu 20.04 LTS (with Xfce).  They all use the same Ubuntu base system, but as for GUI/desktop functions they differ using different toolkits/libraries thus it matters.

Comment: @guiverc oh yeah. Mine is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNOME

Comment: Please correct your question then, you've tagged you're using Lubuntu with LXQt, Xubuntu with Xfce & Kubuntu with KDE Plasma and **not** Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNOME